# Change first column of several dataframes from character to numeric using for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I am new to R and to Stack Overflow, so please bear with me.

I want to do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df_2022[!is.na(as.numeric(df_2022$c1)), ]
df <- df_2022 %>% mutate_at(c('c1', 'c2'), as.numeric)
df <- na.omit(df)
```

Except for about 100 dataframes. I have stored the names of the dataframes as a list, and want to iterate the above over that list in order to drop all rows that include strings or NAs so that i have a column with numeric values.

Is there anyone out there who has done something similar that has some guidance to share?

I have tried using the above using a for loop and accessing the list of names through index but get back an error code "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". I have also tried using paste0 but without success.

Comment: Hi Joakim! Welcome! If you could share your for loop code that'd be great! :-)

Comment: Keep all the dataframes in a list: `myDfs <- mget(list_of_df_names)` then use lapply to loop through and update the 1st column.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (using map, but easily done with apply/lapply/sapply too)

```
library(tidyverse)

# create toy dataframes
df2022 <- data.frame(c1 = c("1", "2", "3", "boom"),
                     c2 = c("5", "6", "7", "8"),
                     d = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))

df2023 <- data.frame(c1 = c("the", "quick", "brown", "fox"),
                      c2 = c("jumps", "over", "the", "lazy"),   
                     d = "dog")

# add to list
myDfs <- list(df2022, df2023)

# for each dataframe in myDfs, convert c1 and c2 to numeric, then filter to select rows where c1 isn't NA
map(myDfs, ~ .x |>
            mutate(across(c(c1, c2), as.numeric)) |> 
            filter(!is.na(c1)))
```

Output:

```
[1]]
  c1 c2 d
1  1  5 a
2  2  6 b
3  3  7 c

[[2]]
[1] c1 c2 d 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Notes:

1. Instead of converting c1 to numeric, then checking for NAs, then selecting non-NA rows, only to then convert c1 and c2 again on the next row, you can just convert them once, then filter out the rows where c1 is NA